# Installing openssl 1.0.2g on jessie

Tags: raspbian-jessie, software-installation, apt

I need to use **libssl-dev 1.0.2g** to compile some old codes.

I followed the guides in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724184/how-to-compile-curl-with-latest-openssl-1-0-2-debian) but it does not work in my case.
This is my */etc/apt/sourcelist*

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
```

From `apt-cache madison openssl1.0`, I can see:

```
openssl1.0 | 1.0.2r-1~deb9u1 | http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch/main Sources**
```

But running `sudo apt-get install openssl1.0` gives:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package openssl1.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'openssl1.0'
```

Please let me know if you have any insight or ideas. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

*Please only us openssl1.0 is you really need to. Otherwise, use the newer and more secure openssl1.1.*

To tell apt to use the old version from the jessie repository (which you already have in your sources.list) , you have to add `/jessie` to the end. For example:

```
$ sudo apt install openssl/jessie
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Selected version '1.0.1t-1+deb8u11' (Raspbian:oldstable [armhf]) for 'openssl'
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libssl1.0.0
```

And for the libary you can just do `sudo apt install libssl1.0.0`.

Comment: Thanks for answering but the version that I need is 1.0.2g. To install version 1.0.1 is easy and straightforward. This is for compiling legacy codes.

Comment: @Dave you might have to compile from source then.